# Neural Networks - Back Propogation

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network

The following code is my implementation of neural network (1 hidden layer) trying to predict some number based on input data.

- Number of input node: 11
- Number of nodes in hidden layer: 11
- Number of nodes in output layer: 1
- `m`: number of training examples, here = 4527
- `X`: `[11, m]` matrix
- `y`: `[1, m]` matrix
- `w1`: weights associated from input layer to hidden layer
- `b1`: bias vector associated from input layer to hidden layer
- `w2`: weights associated from hidden layer to output layer
- `b2`: bias vector associated from hidden layer to output layer
- `alpha`: learning rate
- `ite`: number of iteration, here = 10000

Since I'm trying to predict a continuous value output, I'm using sigmoid function in input layers and identity function in output layer

```
def propagate(X,y,w1,b1,w2,b2,alpha,ite):
    assert(X.shape[0] == 11)
    assert(y.shape[0] == 1)
    assert(X.shape[1] == y.shape[1])
    m = X.shape[1]
    J = np.zeros(shape=(ite,1))
    iteNo = np.zeros(shape=(ite,1))
    for i in range(1,ite+1):
        z1 = np.dot(w1,X) + b1
        a1 = sigmoid(z1)
        z2 = np.dot(w2,a1) + b2

        dz2 = (z2-y)/m
        dw2 = np.dot(dz2,a1.T)
        db2 = np.sum(dz2, axis=1, keepdims=True)
        dz1 = np.dot(w2.T,dz2)*derivative_of_sigmoid(z1)
        dw1 = np.dot(dz1,X.T)
        db1 = np.sum(dz1, axis=1, keepdims=True)

        w2 = w2 - (alpha*dw2)
        b2 = b2 - (alpha*db2)
        w1 = w1 - (alpha*dw1)
        b1 = b1 - (alpha*db1)

        iteNo[i-1] = i
        J[i-1] = np.dot((z2-y),(z2-y).T)/(2*m)

    print(z2)    
    return w1,b1,w2,b2,iteNo,J
```

I have tried both the ways (With feature normalization and scaling & without) but my cost function varies as follows with respect number of iterations (Plotted J).

On $x$-axis: Number of iteration, On $y$-axis: Error $\times 10^{12}$.
[image: On x-axis: Number of iteration, On y-axis: Error * 10^12]

Please help!